# How to show the indeterminate progress icon in a custom PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity, android-progressbar

```
public class MyPreferences extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        ...
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setProgressBarVisibility(true);
    }
}
```

At the first requestWindowFeature() call, this throws:

```
    ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16406): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

Clearly I've not added any content at this point. Has the PreferenceActivity changed some state during the super.onCreate() which causes any children to think it has? Or is there some manifest attribute I should be using?

I should also point out I'm creating these Preferences without xml, i.e. entirely programmatically, but the code snippet is enough to show the problem appears to arise in either case.

Comment: Please seperate your logcat into blocks.

Comment: Because 'compound' activities (PreferenceActivity, ListActivity) etc manage standard view components themselves, then your suspicion about super.onCreate() is probably correct (it is setting the content view). Try moving that line after the lines to request the window features.

Comment: MisterSquonk You've got it! Although I was almost there, I actually held back playing with the location of the super call because of it being mandatory when in a constructor. We're not in that situation here, but it's still the first (or last) line more often than not. Well, you live and learn - thanks. How can I award the answer to you?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you have super.onCreate() before requestWindowFeature(). Since this is a PreferenceActivity, there are some standard items on the screen that are created in onCreate().

Simply move onCreate() below requestWindowFeature().